# How do I make geojson in2csv create separate columns for longitude & latitude?

Tags: csvkit

`in2csv -f json 'list.geojson' > 'list.csv'`

Generating a CSV of points from a GeoJSON file in my project using a Makefile and I'd like to have Longitude and Latitude of points explicitly. Instead I get this column as the closest thing in my CSV:

`geojson
{"type": "Point","coordinates": [36.69965744, -3.3910409]}`

There was an issue that has now been resolved two months ago:
https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/issues/185

I saw this downvoted question, so I hope I don't face the same fate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768104/whats-happened-to-csvkit-1-0-0

How do I install CSVkit 1.0 as it appears to be in prerelease or beta somewhere since Jan 2016? Even the [documentation for it](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/540/tutorial/1_getting_started.html#installing-csvkit) online says that the version is on `pip` but it is not. Alternatively, is there a simple python or commandline tool which might be good in a workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSVkit 1.0 was released a week ago! It has this feature. Check it out.